# Web scraper returning zero in terminal

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this website

https://www.merinfo.se/search?d=c&ap=1&emp=0%3A20&rev=0%3A100&who=bygg&bf=1&page=1

And I've put a `def getQuestions(tag)` in the who={tag} part of the url and that works fine. When I try to add `def getQuestions(tag, page`) page={page} it just returns 0 in the terminal, and I really hope no clue what could be causing this.

Here is the full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'}

questionlist = []

def getQuestions(tag, page):
    url = 'https://www.merinfo.se/search?d=c&ap=1&emp=0%3A20&rev=0%3A100&who={bygg}&bf=1&page={page}'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    questions = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'box-white p-0 mb-4'})
    for item in questions:
        question = {
        'title': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-primary'}).text,
        'link': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-primary'})['href'],
        'nummer': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-body'})['href'],
        'address': item.find('address', {'class': 'mt-2 mb-0'}).text,
        'RegÅr': item.find('div', {'class': 'col text-center'}).text,
        }
        questionlist.append(question)
    return

for x in range(1,5):
    getQuestions('bygg', x)
print(len(questionlist))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the string in `url` variable to f-string:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36"
}


def getQuestions(tag, page):
    questionlist = []
    url = f"https://www.merinfo.se/search?d=c&ap=1&emp=0%3A20&rev=0%3A100&who={tag}&bf=1&page={page}"
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    questions = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "box-white p-0 mb-4"})
    for item in questions:
        question = {
            "title": item.find("a", {"class": "link-primary"}).text,
            "link": item.find("a", {"class": "link-primary"})["href"],
            "nummer": item.find("a", {"class": "link-body"})["href"],
            "address": item.find("address", {"class": "mt-2 mb-0"}).text,
            "RegÅr": item.find("div", {"class": "col text-center"}).text,
        }
        questionlist.append(question)
    return questionlist


out = []
for x in range(1, 5):
    out.extend(getQuestions("bygg", x))

print(len(out))
```

Prints:

```
80
```

Comment: Thank you (again)! I would've NEVER figured this out lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your url to this:

```
url = f'https://www.merinfo.se/search?d=c&ap=1&emp=0%3A20&rev=0%3A100&who={tag}&bf=1&page={page}'
```

You didn't quite have your f-Strings set up right

Comment: Thank you! I have no clue what f strings are but you sure helped me out a {great deal}